# Can't field be assigned memory?

Tags: java, android

I am new to Java. I have runtime error at the line containing `myImageViews[0].v1 = new ImageView(context)`. Is something wrong there?

```
class MyImageViews
{
    ImageView v1;
    ImageView v2;
}

MyImageViews[] myImageViews;

protected class MyLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    public MyLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        myImageViews = new MyImageViews[10];
        myImageViews[0].v1 = new ImageView(context); //runtime error at this line   
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created an array that can contain `MyImageViews` instances but have not yet created an instance.  `myImageViews[0]` is null.

Try changing

```
myImageViews = new MyImageViews[10];
```

to

```
myImageViews = new MyImageViews[10];
for (int i = myImageViews.length; --i >= 0;) {
  myImageViews[i] = new MyImageViews();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
 myImageViews[0] = new MyImageViews(); 
 myImageViews[0].v1 = new ImageView(context);
```